# Checking if any words do not contain a vowel in a array by using linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'am tring to Check if any words do not contain a vowel. The answer that I'am expecting is yes or no.

Thes is my code:

```
string sentence = "I'm thinking about buying a house in the mountains.";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

//1. Check if any words do not contain a vowel
IEnumerable<string> query1 = words
       .Where(n => !n.Contains("a") 
                  || !n.Contains("e") 
                  || !n.Contains("o") 
                  || !n.Contains("i") 
                  || !n.Contains("r"));
```

How do I get the answer?

Comment: Continuing from what you do, I think you should use && instead of ||

Comment: are you asking if the sentence contains any vowels, or do you want to find words from the sentence that do not contain vowels?

Comment: Any reason you want to solve it using linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `&&` instead of `||` and then you can simply use the `Any` method like this:

```
bool some_words_do_not_have_a_vowel = words
    .Where(n => !n.Contains("a") && !n.Contains("e") && !n.Contains("o") && !n.Contains("i") && !n.Contains("r"))
    .Any();
```

You can get rid of `Where` in this case like this:

```
bool some_words_do_not_have_a_vowel =
    words
    .Any(n => !n.Contains("a") && !n.Contains("e") && !n.Contains("o") && !n.Contains("i") && !n.Contains("r"));
```

Please note that this is case sensitive. You might want to do case-insensitive search instead.

By the way, r is not a vowel.

Comment: Maybe you also want to check for upper case vowels (e.g. "I"). "I'm" does not have small letter vowels.

Answer (score 1):

To get collection of words without vowels, you could have a collection of vowels to be checked against:

```
var vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o', 'A', 'I', 'U', 'E', 'O' };
```

And then you check each string (word) if a word contains any vowel in the collection. You only take the words which do *not* contain any vowel:

```
var query = words.Where(x => !x.ToCharArray().Any(c => vowels.Contains(c)); //get words without vowels.
```

If you want to check if any of the words have vowels from all your collections. Simply use the query result with Any:

```
bool result = query.Any();
```

Or you could even check the result based on your original string.